# send keyboard input to firestick via adb

Tags: android, batch-file, variables, adb

I've been trying to write a batch so I can type on my PC via adb and send input to firestick tv.

I have accomplished this with the following script:

```
:Start 
adb connect 1XX.1XX.1.X1X 
set /p intxt=Type...  
adb shell input keyboard text "%intxt%" 
pause 
GOTO Start
```

But if you send text input to device via adb you need to add `%S` to enter spaces between words. For example for "Hello World" you need to input `Hello%sWorld`

Please HELP! I have been trying for week with no results.

This is the closest I have gotten to a solution, but it doesn't seam to work:

```
set filename=%filename: ="%s"%
```

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion 
SET "intxt=something containing spaces"
set "intxt=!intxt: =%%s!"

SET intxt

ECHO adb shell input keyboard text "%intxt%"

FOR /f %%x IN ("%intxt%") DO ECHO %%x

GOTO :EOF
```

Seems to work with `echo` - whether `adb` sees it the same way is for you to experiment with and report back...